# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function in Ionic 4 app with ECharts

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, echarts

I'm trying to integrate [ECharts](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/index.html) into an Ionic (4) app following this guide:

https://golb.hplar.ch/2017/02/Integrate-ECharts-into-an-Ionic-2-app.html

I installed all the modules as follows (i add "ionic info" output):

```
D:\e-charts-debug>ionic info
√ Gathering environment info - done!

Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.1
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : none
   Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (0 plugins total)

System:

   NodeJS : v8.11.4 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 5.6.0
   OS     : Windows 10


D:\e-charts-debug>npm install echarts -S
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ echarts@4.2.0-rc.2
added 2 packages in 176.695s

D:\e-charts-debug>npm install ngx-echarts -S
npm WARN ngx-echarts@4.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0-rc.0 || >=6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-echarts@4.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0-rc.0 || >=6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-echarts@4.0.0 requires a peer of echarts@>=3.1.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ ngx-echarts@4.0.0
added 1 package in 108.986s

D:\e-charts-debug>npm install @types/echarts -D
npm WARN ngx-echarts@4.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0-rc.0 || >=6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-echarts@4.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0-rc.0 || >=6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-echarts@4.0.0 requires a peer of echarts@>=3.1.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @types/echarts@4.1.1
added 1 package in 108.858s
```

I also modified `tsconfig.json` and `app.module.ts` as follows:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,

    ...

    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "echarts": ["node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts.min.js"]
    }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import {NgxEchartsModule} from "ngx-echarts";

...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgxEchartsModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
...
```

In home.ts and home.html i just added a single chart like the example does:

home.ts:

```
    import { EChartOption } from 'echarts';

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    export class HomePage {

        chartOption: EChartOption = {
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category',
                data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
            },
            yAxis: {
                type: 'value'
            },
            series: [{
                data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
                type: 'line'
            }]
        }
}
```

home.html:

```
<ion-content padding>
      <div echarts [options]="chartOption" class="demo-chart"></div>
    </ion-content>
```

However, when i serve the app i get this error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at ChangeFilter.notFirstAndEmpty (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:181834:67)
    at NgxEchartsDirective.ngOnChanges (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:181941:16)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:13831:19)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:15359:20)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:15302:16)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:16195:76)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:16136:13)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///AppModule/HomePage.ngfactory.js:40:5)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:16121:21)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:15268:14)
    at c (http://localhost:8101/build/polyfills.js:3:19752)
    at Object.reject (http://localhost:8101/build/polyfills.js:3:19174)
    at NavControllerBase._fireError (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:74789:16)
    at NavControllerBase._failed (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:74782:14)
    at http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:74829:59
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8101/build/polyfills.js:3:14976)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:6184:33)
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8101/build/polyfills.js:3:14916)
    at r.run (http://localhost:8101/build/polyfills.js:3:10143)
    at http://localhost:8101/build/polyfills.js:3:20242
```

Is it just an import or version issue? If so, how can i solve it?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**

Like the answers below suggest, i tried to install an older ngx-echarts version (my angular version is `5.2.10`):

```
D:\e-charts-2.0.0>npm install echarts -S
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ echarts@4.2.0-rc.2
added 2 packages in 38.188s

D:\e-charts-2.0.0>npm install ngx-echarts@2.2.0 -S
npm WARN ngx-echarts@2.2.0 requires a peer of echarts@>=3.1.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ ngx-echarts@2.2.0
added 1 package in 31.035s

D:\e-charts-2.0.0>npm install @types/echarts -D
npm WARN ngx-echarts@2.2.0 requires a peer of echarts@>=3.1.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @types/echarts@4.1.1
added 1 package in 16.213s
```

Now i see a strange npm warning on "echarts peer", since my version should be fine.

When i launch my app with `ionic serve` i get this error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: echarts is not defined
ReferenceError: echarts is not defined
    at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:123341:61
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14976)
    at r.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10143)
    at NgZone.runOutsideAngular (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5082:69)
    at NgxEchartsDirective.createChart (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:123341:29)
    at NgxEchartsDirective.onOptionsChange (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:123396:36)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:123363:76)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrSetError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:35962:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:35902:27)
    at Subscriber._next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:35840:26)
    at c (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19752)
    at Object.reject (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19174)
    at NavControllerBase._fireError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:51258:16)
    at NavControllerBase._failed (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:51251:14)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:51298:59
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14976)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5134:33)
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14916)
    at r.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10143)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20242
```

I used a new project, doing the same imports process, except from the different ngx-echarts version installed.

**EDIT 2**

This is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps (remove if not needed) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>

  <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));
    }
  </script>-->

  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
       It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "echarts": ["node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts.min.js"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/__tests__/*.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

After including `<script src="../node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>` in index.html file the error still remains:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: echarts is not defined
>   ReferenceError: echarts is not defined

Comment: When did you get the error? in browser? or in `ng serve`?

Comment: check my answer if you Angular version is 5x

Comment: I get the error when i launch my app on browser with ionic serve. I'm checking version right now

Comment: if you are using Angular cli then you can check using `ng -v` or else check your package.json

Comment: Are you using Angular cli?

Comment: check if the path exists here in tsconfig.json  "echarts": ["node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts.min.js"]

Comment: @Niladri: as i said in my question, i added "paths": {"echarts": ["node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts.min.js"] } in ts.config.json. My project is a ionic project, so it does not include a file named angular.cli.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are using Angular 5x version , but the version of ngx-echarts you are using is compatible with Angular 6 . As it seems from this warning -

```
npm WARN ngx-echarts@4.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0-rc.0 || >=6.0.0 but none is installed.
```

It also mentioned in the README of ngx-echarts

```
Latest version @npm:

    v4.0.0 for Angular >= 6
    v2.3.1 for Angular < 6 (Please refer to https://github.com/xieziyu/ngx-echarts/blob/v2.x/README.md)

Github branches:

    master for Angular >= 6
    v2.x for Angular < 6
```

Here is a similar issue in Github https://github.com/xieziyu/ngx-echarts/issues/113

So you can install it like -

> npm install ngx-echarts@2.2.0 -S

or else you can specify the version in your package.json for `ngx-echarts`

**Updated Answer**

After looking into your project , it seems that the path to the `echarts.min.js` is not loaded correctly by your ionic app. So I included the path to the `echarts.min.js` in the root `index.html` file of your ionic project. It is working now -

Here is the code which is added -

```
<html>
  <head>
<script src="../node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
<my-app>loading</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

You need to adjust the path according to your project structure. Here is a stackblitz sample which I created with the same package version that you are using.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eml14x

You can also check the guide for the 2x version here.

https://github.com/xieziyu/ngx-echarts/tree/v2.x

**second update**

The above change would work for angular cli, but for ionic the script files should be available in the `www` folder after the build ,hence you can copy the `echarts.min.js` file from `../node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts.min.js` to your `src/assets` folder and use the below path in your `index.html` .

```
<script src="assets/echarts.min.js"></script>
```

Please check the location of your tsconfig.json file , the path to the `echarts` library depends on it given in the `baseUrl` . 
Check this 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Comment: Thanks for you answer, please check my Edit

Comment: @Ansharja check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6qwfdv?file=.angular-cli.json also check if the path for echart is given in the tsconfig file

Comment: @Nilandri i tried to import the script directly in index.html, but unfortunatly it's still not working

Comment: @Ansharja can you post your index.html and tsconfig.json? What is the error now?

Comment: However i'm using echarts@3.1.1 to avoid that npm warning during installation

Comment: @Ansharja in the stackblitz example i am using the same version

Comment: Always the same, i posted it on the bottom: Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: echarts is not defined ReferenceError: echarts is not defined

Comment: Your second update seems to work: running app on browser (ionic serve) and publishing it in platform browser it works fine. I will test the app soon on my android device. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Ansharja you are welcome.. let me know if there are any issue. is the bounty still active?

Comment: I had to wait 24 hours to give bounty ... Now it's yours !

Answer (score 1):

You have correct setup but the problem is with your compatibility issues:

```
npm WARN ngx-echarts@4.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0-rc.0 || >=6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-echarts@4.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0-rc.0 || >=6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-echarts@4.0.0 requires a peer of echarts@>=3.1.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

When you read `ngx-echarts` README you will se ethis note:

> Latest version @npm:
>
> `v3.2.0` for Angular >= 6
>
> `v2.3.1` for Angular < 6
>
> Github branches:
>
> `master` for Angular >= 6
>
> `v2.x` for Angular < 6

So in your package.json change `"ngx-echarts": "4.0.0"` to `"ngx-echarts": "~2.3.1"`, delete your `node_modules` folder, then run `npm i` command again.

And follow instructions of this branch: https://github.com/xieziyu/ngx-echarts/tree/v2.x

OR better choice if you just starting with the project, go with Ionic with Angular version 6 instead of version 4/5, should be logger support of it.

Actually Ionic 4 I think already starting with version 6 as I remember, not sure how you got Angular 4/5.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, please check my Edit

Comment: 1 for your useful answer